# Hibernate bidrectional many-to-many delete element throws exception

Tags: hibernate-mapping

I have a bidirectional many-to-many mapping between two classes Project, and ProductCatalogItem. The mapping defined in the Project hbm file is as follows-

```
<set name="catalogItems" table="PAS_PRODUCT_CATALOG_PROJECT"
     inverse="false" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
    <key column="PROJECT_ID_" />
    <many-to-many column="PRODUCT_CATALOG_ITEM_ID_" class="com.palamida.appsec.model.ProductCatalogItem" />
</set>
```

Mapping in ProductCatalogItem is defined as follows-

```
<set name="itemInProjects" table="PAS_PRODUCT_CATALOG_PROJECT"
     inverse="true" lazy="true">
    <key column="PRODUCT_CATALOG_ITEM_ID_" />
    <many-to-many column="PROJECT_ID_" class="com.palamida.appsec.model.Project" />
</set>
```

There are three tables defined -
PROJECT, PRODUCT_CATALOG_ITEM, and PAS_PRODUCT_CATALOG_PROJECT (the join table)

The Project class has the catalogItems

```
private Set<ProductCatalogItem> catalogItems = new HashSet<ProductCatalogItem>();
```

ProductCatalogItem has the itemsInProject

```
private Set<Project> itemInProjects = new HashSet<Project>();
```

Each of the attributes have appropriate getters, and setters.
There's logic that adds / removes items from the ProductCatalogItem as follows-

```
public void updateProductCatalogItemsToProject(Project project,
                                        Map<EntityOperationEnum,Set<ProductCatalogItem>> modifiedCatalogItems) {
    if (project != null && modifiedCatalogItems != null && !modifiedCatalogItems.isEmpty()) {
        Set<ProductCatalogItem> newCatalogItems = modifiedCatalogItems.get(EntityOperationEnum.ADD);
        Set<ProductCatalogItem> deleteCatalogItems = modifiedCatalogItems.get(EntityOperationEnum.REMOVE);

        if (newCatalogItems != null && !newCatalogItems.isEmpty()) {
            project.getCatalogItems().addAll(newCatalogItems);    
        }
        if (deleteCatalogItems != null && !deleteCatalogItems .isEmpty()) {
            project.getCatalogItems().removeAll(deleteCatalogItems );    
        }
    }
}
```

When there are only elements to be added, data is inserted into the link table. But when items are to be removed, then I run into the following exception-

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not initialize a collection: [com.palamida.appsec.model.ProductCatalogItem.childProductCatalogItems#17]; SQL [select   childprodu0_.PROJECT_ID_ as PROJECT9_89_1_, childprodu0_.ID_ as ID1_1_, childprodu0_.ID_ as ID1_89_0_, childprodu0_.VERSION_ as VERSION2_89_0_, childprodu0_.ITEM_NUMBER_ as ITEM3_89_0_,  childprodu0_.ITEM_NAME_ as ITEM4_89_0_, childprodu0_.ITEM_DESCRIPTION_ as ITEM5_89_0_, childprodu0_.PLATFORM_NAME_ as PLATFORM6_89_0_, childprodu0_.RELEASE_NAME_ as RELEASE7_89_0_, childprodu0_.PARENT_ID_ as PARENT8_89_0_ from PAS_PRODUCT_CATALOG_ITEM childprodu0_ where childprodu0_.PROJECT_ID_=? order by childprodu0_.ITEM_NAME_ asc]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not initialize a collection:  [com.palamida.appsec.model.ProductCatalogItem.childProductCatalogItems#17]
at    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:635)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column   'childprodu0_.PROJECT_ID_' in 'field list'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57
```

Shouldn't the SELECT be having a join on the PAS_PRODUCT_CATALOG_PROJECT table based on PROJECT_ID_? I don't see that happening. Is there anything that Iam missing in the mapping? 
Can you please help me on this?

Comment: I need to mention that both the classes have equals and hashcode implemented appropriately

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the issue. It was with my mapping of cascade="all-delete-orphan". According to hibernate docs

```
It does not usually make sense to enable cascade on a many-to-one or many-to-many association. 
In fact the @ManyToOne and @ManyToMany don't even offer a orphanRemoval attribute. 
Cascading is often useful for one-to-one and one-to-many associations.
```

So when I was trying to remove from the association, hibernate tried to removed it from the CATALOG_ITEM table with the join column "PROJECT_ID_". Hence the error.
Once I modified it to "all", things started working.